# Maas network connections

Tags: networking, maas

I have looked and looked, but cannot find a drawing that will help.. Maybe someone can answer a question??

I just need to know what connections to make on my servers to enable maas.

Server NIC one to outside network
Server NIC 2 to switch

Maas client1 switch to ilo2?
Maas client1 switch to em1?

I need to know if on the maas clients I need two connections.. One to the ilo port and one to a NIC?

On the maas controller, just a connection to the real world and a connection to the maas switch??

Help, please!

Roger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to set it up as you wish, but generally people do one of two configurations:

```
internet <---------> (nic1) server (nic2) <----------> (nodes)

internet <---------> switch ----- (nodes)
                       |
                       -----> server
```

The former needs ip_forward turned on in the kernel.

The iLOs can be on their own network or the existing network, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi, thanks! On the former, I presume that a switch is between server NIC 2 and the nodes.. Also, ilo traffic (ipmi) on the same network as maas traffic??

Answer (score 0):

1. MaaS server NIC1 <------> switch1 (connected to Internet)
2. Nodes ilo ports <------> switch2 (not connected to Internet)
3. MaaS server NIC2 <-----> switch2

This is the main concept if you want to separate the management traffic from regular public traffic, but there is more to it than just this simple connection.